# Module not found: Can't resolve './PlatformColorValueTypes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have just started learning React Native and wanted to add styleSheet it seems doesn't work, I'm trying to solve an issue but I'm still stuck please can someone help me to solve this issue. by the way I am using react native.

**Console log**

[image]

**Browser result:**
[image]

here is my code below :

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 100,
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        
      },
      tinyPic: {
        width: 90,
        height: 90,
        top: -10
      },
    
      gauge: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 140,
        height: 140,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      
      label1: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top:15,
        right: '115%',
        padding: 4

      },
      label2: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top:15,
        left: '115%',
        padding: 4

      },
      label3: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 145,
        left: '95%',
        padding: 4

      }
   
    });
```

Comment: Can we see your code where this error happens? It looks like you're using Stylesheet wrong, but the community cannot help you without more details

Comment: @user3812411 I updated the question you can check it now

Comment: How are you importing Stylesheet?

Comment: @user3812411 import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

Comment: Which version of React native are you using? And are you using expo or vanilla React-Native?

Comment: @user3812411 I'm using expo and for version react native : ^0.66.0

Comment: Same error with SDK 47 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by updating react-native :

`npm i https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz --save -force`

Comment: Having the same issues with SDK 47

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in an Expo React Native (SDK 47) app, where Webpack told me,

```
Exporting with Webpack...
Failed to compile
ModuleNotFoundError: ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/normalizeColor.js
Cannot find module: './PlatformColorValueTypes'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install ./PlatformColorValueTypes.
```

I looked into `./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/normalizeColor.js` and confirmed that it called `require('./PlatformColorValueTypes')`.

When I looked inside `./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/`, I saw that Webpack was correct that `normalizeColor.js` did not have a sibling file named `PlatformColorValueTypes.js`. But there were sibling files named `PlatformColorValueTypes.ios.js` and `PlatformColorValueTypes.android.js`.

To resolve this, I edited my `webpack.config.js` file to include `.ios.js`, `.android.js`, and `.web.js` extensions as ones that would be resolved by Webpack:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".ios.js", ".android.js", ".web.js"]
}
```