# Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform' '../Utilities/Platform'

Tags: javascript, windows, react-native, expo

I'm quite new to react-native and I trying to run expo-cli in browser mode.

However, there are two kinds of errors:

- Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
- Module not found: Can't resolve './PlatformColorValueTypes'

Besides, nothing is shown on the localhost webpage (http://localhost:19006/).

[image]

Here is my code (App.js).

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { borderColor } from "react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ReactNativeStyleAttributes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <View style={styles.moziBox}></View>
        <View style={styles.gazoBox}></View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  box: {
    height: 100,
    width: "100%",
    borderColor: "lightblue",
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  moziBox: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    padding: 16,
  },
  gazoBox: {
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
});
```

I googled the errors and got webpages like [javascript - Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871341/module-not-found-cant-resolve-utilities-platform) or [javascript - Module not found: Can't resolve './PlatformColorValueTypes' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583163/module-not-found-cant-resolve-platformcolorvaluetypes) but none of them helped so much.

I made sure that react and react-native packages are installed properly.

- react@18.2.0 | MIT | deps: 1 | versions: 1120
- react-native@0.70.4 | MIT | deps: 32 | versions: 1174

How should I solve this?